# Can't seem to delete element in object literal

Tags: javascript, json, object-literal

I have a JSON object literal from which I'm trying to delete an element (let's say apples). I've tried many things, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

```
var JSON = {
    "fruits": [{
        "name": "oranges",
        "quantity": "3"
    },{
        "name": "apples",
        "quantity": "2"
    },{
        "name": "bananas",
        "quantity": "3"
    }
]};

console.log(JSON);
delete JSON.fruits[1];
console.log(JSON);
```

Calling the above code results in the object being removed, but it looks like then inserts the key before the 3rd object. Have a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdu0f3vv/4/). I don't want that to happen.

That's what happens in the Fiddle. But then in my live script however, it looks like it replaces the deleted object with the word `null` which breaks my script.

I've also tried many variations of `.splice()` but that seems to be for arrays, rather than object literals.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your fiddler has a typo!!!!

Comment: Thanks @Leo - fixed!

Comment: Your title says "delete element in object literal", yet you seem to actually to be trying to delete an object in an array.

Comment: @torazaburo you're absolutely correct. When I wrote the question, I thought I _was_ trying to delete an object literal. Turns out that was incorrect! I think I need to brush up on the difference again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for the array inside of the object.

`delete` deletes the object, but you get an undefined element of the array.

```js
var object = { fruits: [{ name: "oranges", quantity: "3" }, { name: "apples", quantity: "2" }, { name: "bananas", quantity: "3" }] };

object.fruits.splice(1, 1);
console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks! That works! I could have sworn that I had tried this already! Strangely through, when I run this code `console.log(activeCaseImplants); activeCaseImplants.implants.splice(1, 1); console.log(activeCaseImplants);` BOTH console logs display the object without the apples element... Weird!

Comment: What does the `.as-console-wrapper` do?

Comment: it looks more, like a console problem, which is out of time. the css makes the whole object viewable in the above window.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.fruits.splice(1, 1); // to remove apples

Knowledge: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice